# Компиляция С в Windows

Tags: c, mingw

Появилась задача, скомпилировать код С под вин. Прочитал, что для этого используют MinGW. Собственно вопрос, будет ли выходной exe файл увеличен существенно в весе, будет ли этот исполняемый файл зависить от каких либо длл файлов? Как быть с кодом, который расчитан на работу с сетью? Можно пожалуйста скинуть информацию по этим пунктам. Заранее спасибо:)

Comment: "Прочитал, что для этого используют MinGW." - не только его. Visual Studio определенно умеет работать с C.
"будет ли выходной exe файл увеличен существенно в весе" - по сравнению с чем, смотря.
"будет ли этот исполняемый файл зависить от каких либо длл файлов" - наверняка будет. Как минимум от системных типа kernel32.dll
"Как быть с кодом, который расчитан на работу с сетью" - смотря как расчитан, что за код.
Уточняйте вопрос, в текущем виде - под закрытие за отсутствие конкретики.

Comment: Увеличен относительно чего? Наличие зависимостей зависит от самого кода. А что не так с кодом, при работе с сетью?

Comment: 1. А почему бы не собрать и не померять? 2. Библиотека сокетов под линукс (или не линукс не важно) на 99% совпадает с библиотекой винды.  Если вы не испольтзуете os-зависимых функций - работать будет. Снифер под линукс хорошо работает под виндой (проверял).

Comment: Все зависит, от вашего кода, что вы там используете, и с сестью проблем не будет, если вы конечно туда стороннего api которое неподдерживается невставили.

Comment: Не, ну всм я думал, что на винде без костылей невозможно скомпилировать код Си. По поводу сети, вот к примеру я пишу код под Debian для отправки POST запросов на сервер. Для этого в винде надо будет использовать другие функции и тд?

Comment: @Corle можно и на линухе и на венде использовать curl или напрямую работать с сокетами. Код будет переносим в таком случае